# Frida: JVM access violation (JNI) lead to Stalker crash

Tags: windows, java-native-interface, instrumentation, frida

I'm trying to stalk a minimal Java program that uses JNI with Frida, but I always run into access violation crashes when the JVM is shut down.
Furthermore, I only seem to ever be able to successfully stalk a JVM process (even if JIT is disabled with `-Xint`), if `Stalker.trustThreshold` is set to `-1`.
If I set the `Stalker.trustThreshold` to anything other than `-1`, the JVM does not crash, but the stalker does not cover any BBs from my custom JNI library `native.dll` (see below).

Here's my Java program:

```java
// Main.java
public class Main {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(20_000); // Enough time to attach to process...
        new Main().sayHello();
    }

    private native void sayHello();
}
```

```cpp
// Main.cpp
#include "Main.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

void sayHello() {
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("output.tmp");
    file << "Hello World\n";
    file.close();
    std::cout << "Current Thread id = " << GetCurrentThreadId() << "\n";
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_sayHello
(JNIEnv *, jobject) {
    sayHello();
}
```

```bash
# Compile native library (Windows)
cl.exe /LD /EHsc /I "%JAVA_HOME%\include" /I "%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" Main.cpp /link /DLL /DEBUG /OUT:native.dll

# Compile Java code
javac Main.java

# Run program
java -cp . -Djava.library.path=%cd% Main
```

My frida script looks as follows:

```py
# frida-agent.py
import sys
import frida

def on_message(message, data):
    print(str(message))

def main():
    device = frida.get_local_device()
    pid = -1
    for proc in device.enumerate_processes():
        if sys.argv[1] in [str(proc.pid), proc.name]:
            pid = proc.pid
            break
    session = device.attach(pid)
    print("Attaching to PID=" + str(pid))

    script = session.create_script(
        """
Stalker.trustThreshold = -1;
const moduleMap = new ModuleMap();
moduleMap.update();

const createCoverageMap = (events) => {
    moduleMap.update();
    const coverageMap = {};
    for (const event of events) {
        const [start, _] = event;
        const pStart = new NativePointer(start);
        const module = moduleMap.find(pStart);
        if (module) {
            const offset = pStart.sub(module.base).toInt32();
            if (!(module.path in coverageMap)) {
                coverageMap[module.path] = 0;
            }
            coverageMap[module.path] += 1;
        }
    }
    return coverageMap;
};

const stalkThread = (threadId) => {
    Stalker.follow(threadId, {
        events: {
            call: false,
            ret: false,
            exec: false,
            block: false,
            compile: true,
        },
        onReceive: function (events) {
            const bbEvents = Stalker.parse(events, {stringify: false, annotate: false});
            send({coverage: createCoverageMap(bbEvents)});
        }
    });
} 

const currentThreads = Process.enumerateThreads();
for (const thread of currentThreads) {
    console.log("Stalking thread: " + thread.id);
    stalkThread(thread.id);
}
"""
    )
    script.load()
    script.on("message", on_message)
    sys.stdin.read()
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When attaching with `python frida-agent.py 8232` the generated output is:

```
Current Thread id = 9632
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000287f70dae25, pid=8232, tid=0x00000000000025a0
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_292-b10) (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.292-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000287f70dae25
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\workspace\simple-jni-app\hs_err_pid8232.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-support/issues
#
```

Do you have any idea on (1) how to prevent the JVM to crash and (2) set the `Stalker.trustThreshold` to anything other than `-1` and still cover BBs from `native.dll`?

Help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the `hs_err_pid8232.log`?

Comment: yes, it didn't really help me in narrowing down the problem. What I found out though, is that the crash does not occur with JDKs>=11. I'm stuck with JDK8, so it doesn't fix the problem for me, but at least I know it is likely to be related to an issue in a specific JDK version.

Comment: Correcting my last comment: It does occur on JDK>=11 as well with a slightly more complex application. Seems to be related to some JVM internals I guess. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps, it would help to include the contents of the log file.